# Why are posts randomly disliked

Tags: discussion, downvotes, post-ban, quality-filter

Every time I post a question, for some reason I get 1 dislike always in beginning first second of the post.

But then it's countered by likes which is good. But problem is that I can't post another question for few days because of 1 dislike, which is odd.

Is it a bug or something? Because it annoys me so much that when a post is posted it instantly gets 1 dislike and gives me cooldown for few days (In Stack Overflow).

Comment: It does not look random at all.  Just be careful, drawing attention like this makes it too easy to see for a moderator that the upvotes you got are fraudulent.  If you want to keep the right to ask questions by cheating then you have to keep a low profile.

Comment: Even this meta post gets dislikes immediately. I am just trying to show three new users stackoverflow and they all hat the same experience. It got worse - after they had deleted their first question they could not retry - they have to wait for two day and I can not show and help them today. stackoverflow seems to have gotten a very. hostile enviroment for newbies.

Comment: @WolfgangFahl So what is your relation to that user named "IdkGoodName V"?

Comment: @WolfgangFahl I agree. I see Questions which asks for help and do not post codes or anything and just asks and i post questions with code and etc and still get dislikes because low reputation. Stackoverflow only likes high reputation people.

Comment: I mean they could make 5 dislikes and then you get suspended not because of 1 dislike.

Comment: Meh, they belong to same group.  A rapidly growing group that inevitably will [destroy this web site](http://www.shirky.com/writings/herecomeseverybody/group_enemy.html).

Comment: Atleast 2 of your questions don't have a down vote so the basis for this question is wrong.

Comment: @AndréKool: Even better, only two of the questions have up AND downvotes. All others either have no votes, only up or only downvotes.

Comment: They aren't 'dislikes', but downvotes. This isn't Facebook. People find your posts useful and we'll researched (or not).

Comment: @AndréKool Because they are countered by upvotes. Every question i posted had 1 dislike in begging, but then was countered by upvotes.

Comment: At 1000 rep, we can click on the score of a post to see the breakdown. And no, this isn't the case. You have 0 scored posts that are truly 0. Never voted either way

Comment: I had no relation to IdkGoodNameV before this discussion. I am sitting at a different part of the world and experiencing similar problems with a group of Stackoverflow neebies that got frustrated in no time (less than 3 minutes).  Just look at the amount of coverage this post gets ... IMHO it is incredible how people in stackoverflow behave towards people not being part of the stackoverflow community yet. Especially the two day delay after just having done what is expected (deleting a bad question) is not going to motivate ...

Comment: @WolfgangFahl: I think we can all agree that 1) this site does not work like other "help" sites, in that it isn't primarily a help site (although help does occur) and most other sites don't allow the community to grade question/answer quality or to moderate site quality, 2) most new users do not understand this when starting here, and that 3) the learning curve for learning how to use this site well is steep, partly due to the issues above. In my experience, these issues are the main source of frustration to new users, much more so than actual malice towards these individuals.

Comment: I don't know of an easy solution to this problem other than to try to gently encourage the new users to read or re-read the help sites that the site has to offer and to keep trying as best they can.

Comment: @Wolfgang did the questions posted by these three newbies abide by our standards? I am not sure why they have to wait 2 days though, that feels unusual (are they second, third or fourth accounts maybe?) And this post gets downvoted immediately because it's been hashed time and time and time and time again by MANY users. The OP here doesn't even seem to be considering that maybe his Q's aren't up to par. There is a major sense of entitlement in the question. People will react to that. + The fact the OP says things that are verifiable and untrue surely doesn't help

Comment: The questions were too short and had the "wrong" tags (getting far to much audience).  They immediately got downvoted and where flagged to be closed. So I recommended to delete the questions and start from scratch which was not possible in our "training session". May be we need to allow some high reputation member to "sponsor" a newbie question and give it a grace period of a few minutes (15-60) . Also there might be a mode where the question is already there but the visibility can be limited to just a set of specific users so that others can help before it is finally published.

Comment: @Wolfgang you are teaching them how to use Stack... Why didn't you check these things *yourself* before posting? They had a mentor: you. It didn't help apparently. And downvoting a wrongly tagged question is fully expected. Oh so the two days thing is because of the timing of your sessions? How is Stack supposed to be held accountable for that?

Comment: @WolfgangFahl: the volume of new questions and the number of newbies joining this site is overwhelming, so much so that setting up any kind of site-arranged mentoring or sponsoring is simply not feasible. This has been discussed before multiple times on this meta site, and I invite you to search out and check these prior discussions. As for "grace period" -- this has also been *well* discussed previously and declined. Again, please search the site for these discussions.

Comment: Nobody is going to spend volunteer time on endless, continual, day-after-day, week-after-week 'NUL terminator missing', 'no space for NUL', 'newline left in buffer by sprintf', 'NPE because I forgot to create object', 'could not be bothered to check return from system calls', 'I don't know how to even print-debug', 'I downloaded the code, don't know how it works but I want you to fix it all', 'Explain', 'Doubts', 'Consider' contrived homework code etc, etc..  If it's 'Computer 101', it's not SO contributors' job to teach it.  SO is good for learning from, but we are not teachers!

Comment: If it is expected that we teach 'Computers 101', someone at SO should say so, then all of us who have no teaching qualifications, no union card and no teachers' salary can pack up and go home.

Comment: You did get feedback on some of the questions in Nicol's answer as well. When someone asks for information like, *What toolkit/framework are you using?* or *Some sample input and desired output would be nice.* you should provide that information.

Comment: Just the title of this post is offensive, consisting as it does of merely an assertion with no evidence.  I could put up better evidence for a 'Why do so many questions from the so-called 'professional or enthusiast' users of new accounts demonstrate gross incompetence wrt. writing code, testing it, debugging it and fixing it?' post;(

Comment: .... and it's Sunday tomorrow.  Yay.

Answer (score 17):

Most of your questions have gotten downvotes because they merit them, not because people are out to get you.

Let's look at the 5 questions from your profile that have downvotes:

- [javascript - Split before specific symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50726869/javascript-split-before-specific-symbol)

  This is a classic "write my code for me" question. I'm not a JavaScript programmer, but `string.split` is not exactly the hardest function to use. Documentation for it is readily available; all you had to do was look for it and apply what you learned. That makes the question poorly researched and therefore worthy of downvotes.
- [What am i doing wrong in RegEx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874364/what-am-i-doing-wrong-in-regex)

  This was closed as a duplicate of a more general question. I'm not sure I agree with that closure, but that's beside the point. Like your previous question, this one doesn't bear any evidence of you doing much to try to solve it on your own. Hence the downvotes.
- [Match everything in string except in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51215996/match-everything-in-string-except-in-quotes)

  The initial form of that question, before another user edited it, was just poorly written. And therefore, worthy of a downvote.
- [PERMISSION_DENIED, when permissions are actually allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51707898/permission-denied-when-permissions-are-actually-allowed)

  That one, I don't really see the problem. I have no knowledge of these technologies, so maybe to an expert this is obvious.
- [Change Title and Icon of C++ app (CROSS-PLATFORM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792525/change-title-and-icon-of-c-app-cross-platform)

  My guess is that your question doesn't really demonstrate an understanding of the C++ programming environment. Your question seems to suggest that you think there's a single function to call to accomplish this task, but of course C++ doesn't work that way. If you had stated that you understood that this was a platform-specific issue which would require different code for different platforms, then it probably would not have gotten a negative response.

  Also, the C++ community on SO generally has higher standards for good, well-researched questions than other communities. If you are going to post in those tags, you need to really show that you have an understanding of what you're doing. Or at least that you took the time to try on your own before asking.

In summary, the downvotes seem to be, more or less, earned by posting relatively poor questions.

Comment: Yeah - I didn't even bother to check.  Sure enough, it's just like all the other posts slamming SO curators because they refuse to provide free labour for no wage and/or teach total newbs how to put one statement after another.  I, for one, have had enough of being exploited as a homework drone and/or Computer 101 teacher:(